# Can not find refresh() function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In this bug report https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4781 a refresh() function in mentioned, how can i call it?

```
$(el).refresh()
```

seems not to be a function in jquery 2.1.1

Comment: [4781](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4781) is markes as duplicate of [4911](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4911) and this one is still marked as open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are just stating that it is part of that function in an upcomming release. When I check the documentation for jQuery UI I cannot see that function in the list:

[jQuery UI api](http://api.jqueryui.com/category/all/)

Neiter is it in the list of available functions for draggable

[Draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/)

EDIT:
Hard for me to know what you are trying to do, other than call that function. Maybe it is this one?

[Refresh Positions](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-refreshPositions)

Comment: when the element is outside of the parent before calling draggable({containment : "parent"}) it is only placed insite the parent after dragging it, i need to immediately position it into the parent

Comment: @wutzebaer ok if you want help with that can you reproduce it in a jsfiddle, so I can take a look at it. Else it is just gonna be guess work from me.

Comment: it pops into the parent only when i start  to drag it

Comment: looks good on first view, but it is duplicated while dragging

Comment: hm ok you hide the duplicate, but it still jumps to the start position when i release the mouse